# using Kivy Garden Graph in KV language

Tags: python, graph, kivy

How do I use the kivy module `garden.graph` inside the kv file? I only found documentation that explained how to use it in the main python script.

I imported the `kivy.garden.graph` in the python file, and I can add the `Graph` inside the kv file, but I didn't find any documentation how to set the size, plots etc.

```
Graph:
    id: graph_test
    plot: MeshLinePlot
```

this gives an error since `MeshLinePlot is not defined`, though I imported it on the python side.

any help would be highly appreciated, maybe we could then add this info to the graph's github readme as well.

Comment: kv language has the #:import statement, you cah find it in the documentation. You must import anything you use in the python part as normal, except a few special functions like the metrics conversion for dp, sp etc.

Answer (score 4):

Building on the answer from piwnk:

I added this to the .kv file:

```
#:import MeshLinePlot kivy.garden.graph.MeshLinePlot
<SetGraph>:
    graph_test : graph_test
    Graph:
    id: graph_test
    plot: MeshLinePlot
    xlabel:'X'
    ylabel:'Y'
    x_ticks_minor:5
    x_tics_major:25
    y_ticks_major:1
    y_grid_label:True
    x_grid_label:True
    padding:5
    x_grid:True
    y_grid:True
    xmin:-0
    xmax:100
    ymin:-1
    ymax:1
    pos: 0, root.height / 6
    size: root.width * 2 / 3 , root.height * 18 / 24
```

In main.py, I added:

```
from math import sin
from kivy.garden.graph import Graph, MeshLinePlot

class SetGraph(Widget):
    graph_test = ObjectProperty(None)

    update_graph(self):
         plot = MeshLinePlot(color=[1, 0, 0, 1])
         plot.points = [(x, sin(x / 10.)) for x in range(0, 101)]
         self.graph_test.add_plot(plot)

class graphLayoutApp(App):
    def build(self):
        disp = SetGraph()
        disp.update_graph()
        return disp


if __name__ == '__main__':
    graphLayoutApp().run()
```

I have changed my original tested solution to more descriptive names. Hopefully, I have not made any mistakes. Let me know if the solution is not complete.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from Mattis Asp was very helpful but didn't quite work for me.  I am new to this, so maybe these things are too obvious to need stating.  But in case it helps someone else at my level, I had to:

1. Indent the properties under the Graph: declaration in the kv file (to get around an "invalid data after declaration" exception from the kv parser.
2. Add these includes:

   language: lang-py

   ```
   from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty  
   from kivy.app import App    
   from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
   ```

to the top of the python file.

3. Name the kv file to match the app class definition, so: graphLayout.kv (I had called it graph.kv so it was just ignored -- newbie mistake!)
4. I was getting "invalid property name" for graph_test : graph_test.  So I commented that out and used the id instead, changing the line

   ```
   self.graph_test.add_plot(plot)
   ```

   to:

   ```
   self.ids["graph_test"].add_plot(plot)
   ```

I bet at least some of these changes have to do with version differences in kivy so, for clarity, I am using kivy 1.9.1 and python 2.7.13.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Here's the solution:

Generally, according to kivy documentation, in kv file:

```
#:import name x.y.z
```

is equivalent to:

```
from x.y import z as name
```

So you should use the following:

```
#:import MeshLinePlot kivy.garden.graph.MeshLinePlot
```

Worked in my case with Graph class but, to be honest, I didn't managed to add this plot to the graph yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think *inclement* was on the right track. Using #:import should be able to import the file.

write this in the kv file:

```
#:import MeshLinePlot
```

it should be able to import the module, as the [kv documentation](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html) shows, also